# Programatic android drawable referencing

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

In an Android program, I am creating a gradientDrawable in java

```
private Drawable getShape(){
        GradientDrawable ib = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, new int[] { 0xff555555,
                0xff999999, 0xffff6600});
        ib.setSize(250, 250);
        ib.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);
        ib.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        ib.setCornerRadius(15);
        ib.setGradientCenter(0.0f, 0.45f);

        return ib;
    }
```

This drawable will be changed based on used inputs in the future.  Is it possible to use this drawable in an xml file located in the drawable folder. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ib"/>
```

My problems as I see it are that nothing resides in drawable/ib.png, but I need to be able to call to it.

I started out using shapedrawable xmls and that worked fine, but I ran into issues when wanting the user to be able to change the image based on their input.  Forgive my rambling, but I am new to this.  I have the idea in my head, but I just can't wrap my brain around how to do it or if it is even possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GradientDrawable is unique in that it can support levels programatically so it's really useful for EditText feedback.   Here is how I've used it, but it's going further down the dynamic path, not the xml path.

This one is used to outline a textview in grey (with  some combination of rounded corners), then the level is used to change the outline to Red or green based.

```
public class FeedbackDrawable extends GradientDrawable {
    private int bgColor;
    private int stroke;
    private int strokeWeight;
    private float dipScale = 1.0f;
    private int radius = 10;

    public static final int FEEDBACK_VALID = 0;
    public static final int FEEDBACK_NEUTRAL = 1;
    public static final int FEEDBACK_ERROR = 2;
    public static final int TOP_LEFT = 0x01;
    public static final int TOP_RIGHT = 0x02;
    public static final int BOTTOM_LEFT = 0x04;
    public static final int BOTTOM_RIGHT = 0x08;
    public static final int TOP_CORNERS = TOP_LEFT|TOP_RIGHT;
    public static final int BOTTOM_CORNERS = BOTTOM_LEFT|BOTTOM_RIGHT;

    public FeedbackDrawable(Context context, int dipRadius, int strokeWeight, int corners) {
        stroke = Color.BLACK;  // or pass them in
        bgColor = Color.WHITE;

        dipScale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        radius = (int)(dipRadius * dipScale);

        this.strokeWeight = strokeWeight;

        float[] radii = new float[]{0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0};
        if ( (corners & TOP_LEFT) > 0){
            radii[0] = radii[1] = radius;
        }
        if ( (corners & TOP_RIGHT) > 0){
            radii[2] = radii[3] = radius;
        }
        if ( (corners & BOTTOM_LEFT) > 0){
            radii[4] = radii[5] = radius;
        }
        if ( (corners & BOTTOM_RIGHT) > 0){
            radii[6] = radii[7] = radius;
        }
        setCornerRadii(radii);
        setUseLevel(true);
        setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        setColor(bgColor);
        setStroke(strokeWeight, stroke);
        setBounds(0, -1, 0, 0);

        setLevel(FEEDBACK_NEUTRAL);
    }




    @Override
    protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
        switch (level){
            case FEEDBACK_ERROR:
                setStroke(strokeWeight, Color.RED);
                break;
            case FEEDBACK_NEUTRAL:
                setStroke(strokeWeight, Color.LTGRAY);
                break;
            case FEEDBACK_VALID:
                setStroke(strokeWeight, Color.parseColor("#4AA02C"));
                break;
            default:
                setStroke(strokeWeight, stroke);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

then to use it:

```
  TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
  // 10 is the corner radius in dips, 3 is the stroke weight 
  tv.setBackgroundDrawable(new FeedbackDrawable(getActivity(), 10, 3, FeedbackDrawable.BOTTOM_CORNERS));
  tv.getBackground().setLevel(FeedbackDrawable.FEEDBACK_NEUTRAL) ;
```

and at any time you can change the feedback by changing the level

```
  tv.getBackground().setLevel(FeedbackDrawable.FEEDBACK_ERROR) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, dangVarmit.  I really need to use it in an xml though, as I will be supplying the xml to a secondary program.  Either that, or can I reference the drawable from different classes and layouts that are separate from the parent java file?

Comment: If you use it as an xml then your ability to change it is lost.  Drawables inflate themselves from xml, but they don't allow for changes and they don't support themed attributes (even though the doc's say they should)  You can create an xml version with levels and then set the levels as above but you have to call mutate() and then you're back to needing code.

Comment: Thank you, dangVarmit.  I was really starting to think that too.  Guess I need to think of another solution.